what is causing the Parser error: syntax error for a module?
I'm trying to fix all of the errors for a 3d model in Open Scad, and in the main module for the where I put the smaller module parts together.  also if there are any problems with how the question shows up I am new to using this website.  First halfSecond half
I've tried looking through all of the section for anything that would be wrong and couldn't find anything and, I can't find anything by looking it up.
This is the code:
    module tardis()
{

   scale([1.5,1.5,1.5]) translate([-8,-15,0])
    
{//tardis
    color([0,0,.6]) translate([0,40,0]) rotate([0,0,0]) cube([15,15,32.5]);
    color([0,0,.6]) translate([0,40,0]) rotate([0,0,0]) cube([13,13,30.5]);
    color([0,0,.6]) translate([-.5,39,32.5]) rotate([0,0,0]) cube([16,16,1.5]);
    color([0,0,.6]) translate([1,40.5,34]) rotate([0,0,0]) cube([13,13,1.5]);
    {//light
    color([1,.9,0]) translate([7.5,47,35.9]) rotate([0,0,0]) cylinder(1.5,1,1);
    color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,35.2]) rotate([0,0,0]) cylinder(0.7,1.05,1);
    color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,37.4]) rotate([0,0,0]) cylinder(0.605,1.05,0);
    color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,36.3]) rotate([0,0,0]) cylinder(.1,1.05,1.03);
        color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,36.9]) rotate([0,0,0]) cylinder(.1,1.03,1.03);
        
            
        
        for (i=[1:5])
        {
        color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,35.2]) rotate([0,0,72*i]) translate([0.95,0,0.7]) cylinder(1.5,.1,.1);
        }
        /*
         color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,35.2]) rotate([0,0,72]) translate([0.95,0,0.7]) cylinder(1.5,.1,.1);
        color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,35.2]) rotate([0,0,144]) translate([0.95,0,0.7]) cylinder(1.5,.1,.1);
        color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,35.2]) rotate([0,0,216]) translate([.95,0,0.7]) cylinder(1.5,.1,.1);
        color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,35.2]) rotate([0,0,288]) translate([.95,0,0.7]) cylinder(1.5,.1,.1);
        */
        color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,35.2]) rotate([0,0,35]) translate([.34,-.25,0.7]) cube([.5,.1,1.5]);
        color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,35.2]) rotate([0,0,35]) translate([.34,.2,0.7]) cube([.5,.1,1.5]);
        color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,35.2]) rotate([0,0,-35]) translate([.34,-.3,0.7]) cube([.5,.1,1.5]);
        color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,35.2]) rotate([0,0,-35]) translate([.34,.15,0.7]) cube([.5,.1,1.5]);
        color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,35.2]) rotate([0,0,-110]) translate([.34,-.25,0.7]) cube([.5,.1,1.5]);
        color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,35.2]) rotate([0,0,-110]) translate([.34,.2,0.7]) cube([.5,.1,1.5]);
        color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,35.2]) rotate([0,0,-180]) translate([.34,-.3,0.7]) cube([.5,.1,1.5]);
        color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,35.2]) rotate([0,0,-180]) translate([.34,.2,0.7]) cube([.5,.1,1.5]);
        color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,35.2]) rotate([0,0,-250]) translate([.34,-.3,0.7]) cube([.5,.1,1.5]);
        color([0,0,.6]) translate([7.5,47,35.2]) rotate([0,0,-250]) translate([.34,.2,0.7]) cube([.5,.1,1.5]);
    }
    color([0,0,.6]) translate([14.5,38.5,0]) rotate([0,0,0]) cube([2,2,32.5]);
    color([0,0,.6]) translate([-1.5,38.5,0]) rotate([0,0,0]) cube([2,2,32.5]);
    color([0,0,.6]) translate([-1.5,54.5,0]) rotate([0,0,0]) cube([2,2,32.5]);
    color([0,0,.6]) translate([14.5,54.5,0]) rotate([0,0,0]) cube([2,2,32.5]);
    color([0,0,.6]) translate([-2,38,0]) rotate([0,0,0]) cube([19,19,1.5]);
    tardissign();
    rotate([0,0,-90]) translate([-55,-40,0]) tardissign();//frount
    rotate([0,0,-270]) translate([40,-55,0]) tardissign();
    rotate([0,0,180]) translate([-15,-95,0]) tardissign();
    translate([0,-1,0]) tardisfacefrount();
    translate([0,15,0]) tardisface();
    rotate([0,0,-90]) translate([-55,-25,0]) tardisface();
    rotate([0,0,-270]) translate([40,-40,0]) tardisface();
}
}


The first half and second half are two different screen shots that I thought would show up as actual images.

Don't make us retype your code from an image.  Post code and errors as plain text.

The code pasted is mostly fine, just missing some other modules likely defined earlier in the full script. It's not really possible to find errors, without the full code, but at a guess, there's maybe a semicolon or a brace missing before the "tardis" module.

I agree with @TorstenPaul, when a semicolon or a brace is missing, the error is often displayed later. This is because the error is not the missing semicolon/brace, it is the fact that there is some code that should've been placed after after a semicolon/brace but was instead placed right away.

The errors you get may depend on openSCAD version. On Debian, using version 2021.01 I only get warnings, due to modules that are not present in your code snippet, but the model gets rendered correctly with the given code. Image of the rendered model
